# Why does the model matrix function ignore creating a dummy for all categories?

Tags: r

Why does it ignore creating the dummy for females?[image]

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

data(titanic_train, package = "titanic")

titanicTib <- as_tibble(titanic_train) %>%
mutate_at(.vars = c("Survived", "Sex", "Pclass"), .funs = factor) %>%
mutate(FamSize = SibSp + Parch) %>%
select(Pclass, Sex, Age, Fare, FamSize)

X <-model.matrix(~ -1 + Pclass + Sex + Age + Fare + FamSize, data=titanicTib)

head(X, 5)
```

Comment: Because `female` is the base level (it comes before `male`).

Comment: Thank you. But why did it not do this for Pclass which has 3 levels? Shouldn't it also have dropped one of the levels?

Comment: Add `contrasts.arg = list(Sex = contrasts(titanicTib$Sex, contrasts = FALSE))` to the `model.matrix` call. `Pclass` has all levels because you have a model without intercept.

Comment: This is because you specified without intercept and I believe the first term would become the baseline. Try```model.matrix(~  Pclass  + Sex+Age + Fare + FamSize, data=titanicTib)``` and ```model.matrix(~  -1+Sex+Pclass  + Age + Fare + FamSize, data=titanicTib)``` to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have all levels of variable `Sex` in the model matrix, add

```
contrasts.arg = list(Sex = contrasts(titanicTib$Sex, contrasts = FALSE))
```

to the `model.matrix` call.

```r
X <- model.matrix(~ -1 + Pclass + Sex + Age + Fare + FamSize, data = titanicTib,
                  contrasts.arg = list(Sex = contrasts(titanicTib$Sex, contrasts = FALSE)))

head(X, 5)
#>   Pclass1 Pclass2 Pclass3 Sexfemale Sexmale Age    Fare FamSize
#> 1       0       0       1         0       1  22  7.2500       1
#> 2       1       0       0         1       0  38 71.2833       1
#> 3       0       0       1         1       0  26  7.9250       0
#> 4       1       0       0         1       0  35 53.1000       1
#> 5       0       0       1         0       1  35  8.0500       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If there is no intercept term, as in the question's example, then the first factor will include all levels but the remaining factors will not because if they did the intercept would lie in the space of both factors introducing non-identifiability into the model.  Note below how each row of the first 3 columns sums to 1 so that the intercept lies in the space of the those columns.  If Sex also included all levels then the intercept would lie its space too.

```
DF <- head(titanicTib, 10)
m <- model.matrix(~. - 1, DF)
m
##    Pclass1 Pclass2 Pclass3 Sexmale Age    Fare FamSize
## 1        0       0       1       1  22  7.2500       1
## 2        1       0       0       0  38 71.2833       1
## 3        0       0       1       0  26  7.9250       0
## 4        1       0       0       0  35 53.1000       1
## 5        0       0       1       1  35  8.0500       0
## 7        1       0       0       1  54 51.8625       0
## 8        0       0       1       1   2 21.0750       4
## 9        0       0       1       0  27 11.1333       2
## 10       0       1       0       0  14 30.0708       1

rowSums(m[, 1:3])
##  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 
##  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Suppose we create a model with Pclass and Sex and force both terms to have all levels.  Then `lm` makes the last level NA since otherwise it would be redundant so it was all pointless. Now suppose we run lm on y <- 1:10 with the following:

```
y <- 1:10
Pclass <- model.matrix(~. - 1, DF[1])
Sex <- model.matrix(~. - 1, DF[2])
X <- cbind(Pclass, Sex)
fm <- lm(y ~ X - 1, DF)
fm
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ X - 1, data = DF)
##
## Coefficients:
##   XPclass1    XPclass2    XPclass3  XSexfemale    XSexmale  
##     4.7778     10.6667      5.5556     -0.6667          NA <-- NA
```

We can get the coefficients of all levels using `dummy.coef` but with treatment contrasts the missing levels will have coefficient of zero which is another way to see why it is all pointless.

We can use different contrasts but that does not change the fact that the intercept will lie in the space of the Sex term if two columns are generated, no matter how they are generated provided they are generated properly and so span the correct space.

```
fm <- lm(y ~.-1, DF[1:2])
dummy.coef(fm)
## Full coefficients are 
##                                        
## Pclass:            1         2         3
##             4.111111 10.000000  4.888889
## Sex:          female      male          
##            0.0000000 0.6666667
```